# Song lyrics database/API

Tags: music

Whwre can I find database/API with song lyrics in English?

I want to find specific song by part of lyric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try musixmatch's api. According to their site  - the api contains more than 14 million lyrics in 50 languages.